# Android - Pathfinding on map.png

Tags: java, android, path-finding

Good morning,

I'm working currently on a pathfinding project. Basically, I got this map on my application :

[image]

And so I just want to determine the shortest way to go from A to B (of course, I can't go through the blue and gray part which are basically walls...)

Is A* algorithm a good way to start ? 
Well if you have any ideas, any suggestions about this problems, tell me ^^

Thank's for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, A* is a good start, assuming you mean to allow movement on the grid only. I mean an agent on a pixel would only travel North, East, South, West and never diagonally. Be warn you will obtain rather un-natural looking paths with 90° and 45° angles everywhere, but this can be mitigated later using some appropriate tie-breaker.

I propose you start using Dijkstra, and once you got that working modify it to implement A* - both algorithms are very close.

---

If instead you intend to allow your agents to travel diagonally from any pixel to any other pixel which has direct visibility, then no, an other algorithm is needed.

Comment: Yeah after fews research, it seems that this is the 2 main algorythm, so I will focus on them !